How to cache get_queryset() when using ForeignKeyWidget
I am importing data using django-import-export but because I use ForeignKeyWidgets there are a lot of database calls making the import very slow for only a few 100 rows (checked with django-debug-toolbar).
On the documentation page of Bulk imports the following is mentioned:

"If you use ForeignKeyWidget then this can affect performance, because it reads from the database for each row. If this is an issue then create a subclass which caches get_queryset() results rather than reading for each invocation."

I believe caching the get_queryset() results could help me, but I have no idea how to do the caching. Could you help me with some example code?
I tried the following but still see the same amount of database calls:
class CachedForeignKeyWidget(ForeignKeyWidget):
    def __init__(self, model, field="pk", use_natural_foreign_keys=False, **kwargs):
        self.cached_queryset = model.objects.all()

        super().__init__(model, field, use_natural_foreign_keys, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self, value, row, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.cached_queryset


I don't have a code sample but it likely means to create a subclass widget, perform the get_queryset() call once and store internally in a dict, and then subsequent lookups can use the dict.

Hi Matthew, I've tried what you mentioned (see edited answer) but the amount of calls is still the same. They are triggered by line 449 in widgets.py (self.get_queryset(value, row, kwargs).get({self.field: val}))

You would have to cache the results in the Widget - i.e. by storing in a map.  Some more information on optimization here and here.

I have tested this using the bulk_import script.
My view is that the QuerySet cache is being used and although you see the SELECT SQL output for the relation table, the cache is being used, therefore the performance hit is minimal.
I can see in my logs that the lookup on the FK table takes negligible time, even when importing 100k rows.
I also see that the cache breakpoint is being hit during import.
If you are seeing a slow import, then there must be something else going on, so it would be useful to understand what the issue is.
Please do your own testing but my view is that the Django QuerySet cache is working correctly and there should be no need to implement your own caching.  I'll update the documentation.
